# isNan using this selector with dynamic content in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Here's the function I'm trying to use

```
$('body').on('click', '.up-vote', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var data = {"action": "voteKarma", "id": $(this).data("id"), "value": $(this).data("val")}
    $.post(window.apiURL, data, function(result) {
        switch(result['status']) {
            case 1:
                var vote_sum_text = $(this).next(".sum").text();
                if (!isNaN(parseInt(vote_sum_text, 10))) {
                    var vote_sum_text = $(this).next(".sum").text();
                } else { alert("isNaN Variable") } 
            break;
    }, 'json');
});
```

When the Ajax result returns **0** It's returning an alert with **isNaN Variable** which is my fallback to debug with problem.

Here's my HTML layout which is grabbed dynamically using another Ajax request there are multiple of these divs listed in `<li>` format :

```
<div class="votes pull-left">
    <a class="up-vote" href="#" data-id="20" data-val="1"><span class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-up"></span></a>
    <span class="sum" style="font-weight:400;color:#666;">
         0
    </span>
    <a class="down-vote" href="#" data-id="20" data-val="0"><span class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-down"></span></a>
</div>
```

In simple terms; when you click `.up-vote` or `.down-vote` it'll send an AJAX request that'll then grab the `text()` of the `.sum` value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try use

```
$(event.currentTarget).next(".sum").text();
```

Because `this` in `.post` does not refer to element

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the following:

```
$('body').on('click', '.up-vote', function(event) {
   event.preventDefault();
   var up_vote_this = $(this);
   ....
   ....
   //now you can use the variable in the success function...

      var vote_sum_text = up_vote_this.next(".sum").text();
```